# Caps on serving files from Google Cloud Storage via App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

In Google App Engine you can set up a daily maximum budget to prevent DDOS and similar attacks from generating huge bills. I cannot find anything similar for Google Cloud Store.

How do I cap downloads to prevent DDOS generating big bills when serving files from Google Cloud Store through PHP using CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl()?

Comment: The 3 times you reference Google Cloud Store, do you mean `Google Cloud Storage`?

Comment: Of course… the tag says so…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to set daily maximum budgets is not currently a feature of Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: I basically have to pipe the files through App Engine, then…

Comment: What if I use getImageServingUrl() instead? In Python that would use Blobstore/AppEngine and be limited by the GAE cap. Is Php different in this resepect?

Comment: getImageServingUrl() works the same in PHP as it does for python & java - uses GAE quotas for bandwidth.